# Putting Frame around Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are plugins that do this, but I feel sure there must be a simpler way.

[image: framing]

I have a frame png that is transparent both inside and outside the frame image.

I have a bootstrap carousel.

I want to put the frame on top of the carousel. I want them to scale simultaneously when the browser is resized.

How do I do this simply, nesting a div inside another div?.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div flex layout="column" class="outer">
    <div class="top">
        <span class="left-spacer"></span>
    <span class="page-header">
        ART
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="middle-constrained">
            <div>
                <img class="artFrame" src="{{artFrame}}">
                <app-image-slider></app-image-slider>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="artSpacer"></span>
    <div class = "artTextboxes">
        <span class="artText">
                “Oh, well, okay, I’ll say, “Congratulations. That’s what we have here. I mean, the press. I don’t care. All Americans living here and for the country will be further destroyed. So we get nothing. What do we have."
        </span>
        <span class="artText">
                "Now, Ford announces a few weeks ago. And I come in from different places. I go to China. They are building other candidates, they literally do whatever the hell kind of energy it is – I don’t want it.”
        </span>
        <span class="artText">
                “I mean – and no matter where we go we fill up the Second Amendment, and leaving only the bad guys and terrorists with guns. No good. Not good.""
        </span>
    </div>
    <span class="artSpacer2"></span>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Shade');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Fjalla+One|Karla');

body {
    display: flex;
}

.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #5BC8AF;
}

.top {
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-center;
}

.left-spacer {
    flex-basis: 95%;
    background-color: #5BC8AF;
}

.page-header {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:  #5BC8AF;
    flex: 1;
    height: 4vh;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
    font-size: 2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #B6DBDE;
 }

 .middle {
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
    overflow:hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-image: url('Melanie.png');
    background-color: rgba(255,153,153,0.6);
    background-blend-mode: lighten;

 }


 .middle-constrained {
    flex-basis: 30%;
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
    align-content: stretch;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

  .artFrame {
    flex: 1;
 }

 .artSpacer {
    order: 3;
    height: 500px;
 }

  .artSpacer2 {
    order: 5;
    height: 500px;
 }

 .artTextboxes {
    order: 4;
    display: flex;
 }

 .artText {
    flex-basis: 33%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: justify;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color:  #B6DBDE;
    color: #67327A;
    border-radius: 10px;
 }

 .artText:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #A7D3D7;
 }

 .artText:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #99CCD1;
 }


app-image-slider {

    flex:1 ;
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Looking at your frame I would go with `border: 10px solid #000` for the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one solution is to have a parent div with it's position set to relative then two images inside the parent, The overlapping one set to position relative while the under image set to position absolute (You will need to much around with max height and widths on parent divs to give it some sort of constraint though): Like so

Edit: added border and confined parent divs for .middle-constrained in jsfiddler example

https://jsfiddle.net/j9s1n0n7/2/

```
        <div class="parentOver">
            <img class="artFrame" src="https://www.mantidproject.org/images/c/ce/Mocking.jpg">
            <img class="overlapImg" src="https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/debut-light.png">
            <app-image-slider></app-image-slider>
        </div>
```

and css

```
.artFrame {
flex: 1;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.overlapImg {
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.parentOver {
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 max-height: 300px;
 }
```

I am not sure if this setup will play nicely with your carousel so you will need to play with it. Your forfront image would need to be at the very least.

Another option is to set your rotating image as the background image in css and your transparent as the image in html but I am sure that would kill your carousel functionality without some serious modifications.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. The combo of flexbox and position: absolute doesn't seem to work. and I need flexbox so I found a way around using  the same nested div approach, but with justify-content: center and align-self: center. Unfortunately, it's not a complete fix coz now I have trouble with my Angular toolbar, but that is a separate issue and I'll post another question. Marking this as your fix

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the frame to be around all images? You could likely create a div around the carousel that has the css you want for the frame.

Comment: Yeah I'm using a div around the carousel, but when I put an img in the div the carousel wraps underneath it. I could use z-index to float the frame on top, but I can't position it right or select the carousel underneath

Comment: Do you have an example of your code and how you are adding the frame div?

Comment: Edited the question to include code - the text is from a Trump speech generator - better than Lorem Ipsum!